# Pulling Public User Information from Instagram (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

so I've been tasked with creating or finding a tool that can pull a users information from Instagram using javascript/jquery. I'm not looking to display the photos and comments etc I just need to know how many likes they're getting on the last 9 photos and how many comments. (Then place it into a html div so it can display on a website and update on reload)

Is this possible using the API? Thank you!

Comment: You could [read the documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) and find out.

Comment: @MikeC The documentation talks about the Python and Ruby libraries.

Comment: It's a REST API. You can access it with any code that can perform REST calls. Python and Ruby might have specific libraries but they're just wrappers around making REST API calls. In fact, they said those libraries are not actively maintained.